# PHP Output buffering prints at end of script

Tags: php, buffer

I'm trying to wrap my brain around buffering, but I cannot get ANY example on this site to work for me.  Nor the samples from php.org.

Here's what I'm using

```html
    ini_set( "output_buffering", "on");
    
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    $x = 1;
    
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    
    while ($x < 10) {
        ob_end_clean();
        ob_start();
        echo $x." asdfasdfasdfasdf <br />";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
        ++$x;
    }
```

Right now the script just prints the entire script out in one shot after the script has finished running.  I've modified my php.ini file and manually turned on output buffering to no avail. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: I want it to print each echo statement AS the script is running, not everything at the end

Comment: it won't work like that... the closes approximation that I can think of that would do that would be to use php as the source of an `Event Stream` initialised by javascript

Comment: I guess `flush()` should come after `ob_flush()`

Answer (score 0):

To support the comment I made - "The closest approximation that I can think of..." I cobbled together a demo which illustrates what I meant by the use of an `EventStream` - perhaps more complicated than is needed but output buffering cannot be used as imagined when asking the question.

If you were to copy this and create a new php file, save and run you ought to see the output as it happens... sort of.

```
<?php
    if( !empty( $_GET['evtstream'] ) && $_GET['evtstream']==true ){
        ob_clean();
        set_time_limit( 0 );
        ob_end_clean();

        function sse( $evtname='evt', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
            if( !is_null( $data ) ){
                echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
                echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
                echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
        }

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

        $i=1;
        $evt=!empty( $_GET['evt'] ) ? $_GET['evt'] : 'tick';
        $count=!empty( $_GET['count'] ) ? $_GET['count'] : 10;

        while( true ){
            if( $i > $count ) break;

            /* send some data back for the SSE listener to process */
            $payload=array(
                'date'          =>  date( DATE_ATOM ),
                'count'         =>  $i,
                'event'         =>  $evt,
                'calculation'   =>  ( rand( 10,999 ) * rand( 300, 5999 ) ) / rand( 0.25, 25 )   #some random task performed by php...
            );
            call_user_func( 'sse', $evt, $payload );

            if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
            @flush();

            sleep( 1 );
            $i++;
        }

        /* 
            Now that the event loop has completed the 10 iterations we 
            need to prevent the eventsource from re-establishing itself
        */
        header('Content-Type: text/html');
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404 );
        echo 'goodbye';
        ob_end_clean();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Output Buffering: Server Sent Events</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Output buffering experiments</h1>
        <div></div>
        <script>
            const EVENT_NAME='ticker';
            const MAX_ITERATIONS=10;

            let evtsource = new EventSource( location.href + '?evtstream=true&evt='+EVENT_NAME+'&ts=' + ( new Date().getTime() )+'&count='+MAX_ITERATIONS );

            let oDiv=document.querySelector( 'div' );

            const create=function(data){
                let node=document.createElement('div');
                    node.innerText=data;
                return node;
            };
            const callback=function(e){
                let json=JSON.parse( e.data );
                let content=Object.keys( json ).map( k => {
                    return [k,json[k]].join('=')
                }).join('&')
                oDiv.append( create( content ) );               
            };
            const errorhandler=function(e){
                evtsource.close();
                oDiv.append( create( 'Terminated' ) );
            };

            evtsource.addEventListener( EVENT_NAME, callback, false );
            evtsource.addEventListener( 'error', errorhandler,false );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you could look at this example of another use of `output buffering` - you'll see that the html has a header (banana...) which is modified by the output buffer callback - this sort of modification wouldn't be possible using DOMDocument on a live document without output buffering.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    function callback( $buffer ){
        if( !empty( $buffer ) ){
            $dom=new DOMDocument;
            $dom->loadHTML( $buffer );
            $h1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0);
            $h1->nodeValue='A giraffe is a large mammal from Africa';
            return $dom->saveHTML();
        }
    }
    ob_start( 'callback' );
    ob_implicit_flush(1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Output Buffering Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bananas are curvy yellow fruit</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```